# SSIS: Extract SQL Data and Split across Flat files based on row count

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssis

I have created a simple SSIS package that queries a table and extracts data to a flat CSV file. In production this extract could be millions of rows and I want to split the flat file destinations into multiple files based on row count.

So create new file each time we hit 100000 rows with filenames something like

- SomeName_01_date.csv
- SomeName_02_date.csv

I have found a paid for tool by ZappySys that will do this but cannot work out how to do it with just the normal SSIS toolbox, I may be missing something really simple.
I have found other posts and videos but some of them involve using additional code outside of the normal tool set, such as the techbrothersit website.

Edit:
After reading up and from the comments this looks to be harder than expected.
If I change process to split the flat files based on a date column in the table would that be more straight forward?

Table has a short date column in this format 2020-07-30, each CSV file would contain just one days worth of extracted data (could be 100K+), that data is then deleted from the table. The deletion will occur after all data has been extracted.

I am trying to use a foreach/forloop container but struggling as this is totally new to me, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are some interesting things here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001776/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-using-powershell - may be easier to write the file once out of SSIS, then split using a simple C# program called in a script task.  This is much easier in UNIX with SPLIT (https://kb.iu.edu/d/afar) - if you've installed a BASH environment you could conceivably do that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate, I have edited the question now as this feels simpler, unsure if you have any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not limit the data via the query that gets executed, either with the [`OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch) or with a predicate you can *slide the window on* with each iteration in SSIS?

Comment: Thanks for this mate, I have edited the question after thinking about it unsure if you have any advice?

Comment: @Stockburn No problem, sounds like you're going with the predicate approach by using a date column to filter on. That will probably work for you.

Comment: Just for those interested I solved this by using a script task to obtain a list of archive dates from the table, dropped the results into a variable and used a foreachloop container to loop through and create flat files.